# awk output and string manipulation

Tags: awk

I need an one-liner, for the following output:

```
STRING='SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: test test test, test v3.2.5.90, test'
echo $STRING | awk '{print $8}'
v3.2.5.90,
```

Desired output is

```
v3.2.5.90
```

So I need to remove the comma at the end. I could pipe it again to sed but this means there has to be a "one-command" solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `,` only appears one time in string?

Comment: No multiple times. Whole output:
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: test test test, test v3.2.7.32.a, test

Comment: `'{gsub(/\,/,""); print $8}'`...

Comment: @fedorqui oh you´re right. copied the wrong string. fixed it

Comment: OK so what is the pattern here? The last block of text before the last comma?

Comment: @fedorqui yes. You could you $(NF-1) too. Still the comma to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $STRING | awk -F', | ' '{print $8}'
```

Works on my end.

Answer (score 1):

This works with grep -version 2.25 on Ubuntu

```
grep -oP '(?<=, test).*(?=,)' <<< "SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: test test test, test v3.2.7.32.a, test"
```

Comment: Probably you need `(?<=, test )`, that is, a space after `test`.

Answer (score 1):

Try ordinary bash (even POSIX/standard `sh`) string tools:

```
STRING='SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: test test test, test v3.2.5.90, test'
OUTPUT=${STRING%,*}
printf '%s\n' "${OUTPUT##* }"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to always capture the version # ( starts with v), then try this

```
echo ${STR} | awk '$0~/^v/' RS=", "
```